# Why `HTMLelement.innerText` adds newline (\n)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, element, getelementbyid

I found this weird behavior of `HTMLelement.innerText` that I can't understand.
Here is an example of the question:

```
// HTML
<div>
    <article id="editor"></article>
</div>

// JavaScript
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
console.log(editor.innerHTML); // prints "\n"

// From 3rd party libraries
var jqueryExample = jquery.parseHTML('<div><article></article></div>')[0];
console.log(jqueryExample.innerHTML); // prints ""

var angularjsExample = angular.element('<div><article></article></div>')[0];
console.log(angularjsExample.innerHTML); // prints ""
```

As you see, when I use `document.getElementById`, element's `innerHTML` has `\n` for some reason.  However, if I use `jquery.parseHTML` or `angular.element`, it doesn't add `\n` and it returns as it is.

It is more interesting if the HTML has more content:

```
// HTML
<div>
    <article id="editor">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Foo</p>
    </article>
</div>

// JavaScript
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
console.log(editor.innerText); // prints "Test\nFoo"
```

But `jquery.parseHTML` and `angular.element`'s `innerText` prints `TestFoo`.  Why is that???

[image: Newlines]

Comment: In your second example, the new line is there because <h1> and <p> are block elements. if you use <span> for both elements there is no new line

Comment: That's not a problem with `getElementById` (that's just a method to get the element). You are doing different things. the `getElementById` finds an element rendered by the browser, angular an jquery code are creaing a new element so it may be different than the first element. What does `jQuery('#editor')[0].innerHTML` return?

Comment: @arieljuod I think your answer is the right answer, could you reply that as an answer? And also, why is different between rendered element and created element?

Comment: `innerText` takes into account layout formatting and inserts whitespace around block elements. Don't use it. Use `.textContent` for getting raw DOM text.

Comment: @Bergi I wouldn't say "Don't use it" for `innerText`. `innerText` are useful in some situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Docs:<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)</sup>

> The `innerText` property of the [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants. As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied it to the clipboard.

On my browser (Chrome 61), I see it insert two newlines in the string:

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
console.log(editor.innerText); // prints "Test\nFoo"
console.log(editor.innerText.length);
console.log(Array.from(editor.innerText))
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div>
    <article id="editor">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Foo</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not add any new lines. It just outputs contents “as is”. In first case, it outputs an empty character, so you do not see it. In the second case, there are four new lines (check below the `editor-2` example about how to output same content as single line).

```js
var editor1 = document.getElementById('editor-1');
console.log('editor-1: [' + editor1.innerHTML + ']'); //-> "[]"

var editor2 = document.getElementById('editor-2');
console.log('editor-2: [' + editor2.innerHTML + ']'); //-> "[<h1>Test</h1><p>Foo</p>]"
```

```html
<div>
  <article id="editor-1"></article>
  <article id="editor-2"><h1>Test</h1><p>Foo</p></article>
</div>
```

Comment: When I debug the code in Chrome Debugger, I see `\n` character

Comment: @KimchiMan Are you sure that you use the same code snippet? What do you see when you run my snippet?

Comment: Hmm it's very weird, I don't see a newline character..but while I am debugging my AngularJS project, I see newlines: https://imgur.com/a/sSymiwR

Comment: @KimchiMan Nothing weird here. As I said, it just outputs exactly what you write. In your case, read your example as `<article id="editor">[newline][space][space]<h1>Test</h1>[newline][space][space]<p>Foo</p>[newline]</article>`

Comment: Okay,, maybe this behavior is from `AngularJS`, but I am not 100% sure..thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem with `getElementById` (that's just a method to get the element). You are doing different things. the `getElementById` finds an element rendered by the browser, angular an jquery code are creaing a new element so it may be different than the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you add some li to this element, that element what you are trying to console.log is still empty. Because you're trying to console.log innerHTML from this element. If you will try to console.log(element.value) it will show you that is undefined, because there is no value.